# Calling gRPC services through a Web API in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, grpc, .net-6.0

I'm in trouble using Web Api's and gRPC's. In this moment I want to have my controllers from an Web Api getting the services from a gRPC project. This is the architecture of my project:

[image]

If my question has not yet been explained, I will tell you by example what I want

Ex:
I have a UserAuthService with a method AddUser

```
public override Task<NewUserResponse> AddUser(NewUserRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
```

This is the proto (gRPC and Web Api use the same except the namespace) ->

```
yntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Grpc_Server_1.Protos";

package UserAuth;

//import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service UserAuth {
    rpc AddUser (NewUserRequest) returns (NewUserResponse);
}

//here is a register
message NewUserRequest {
    string name = 1;
    string email = 2;
    string password = 3;
}

//here i will create a user, put him into a db with a userId and give a message sucess
message NewUserResponse {
    string userId = 1;
    string message = 2;
}
```

This is a method for Web Api

```
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Register(RegisterModel request)
        {
            //lot of code (check if is a valid user, create a user, save changes)
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

And this is .csproj I use

Web Api

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Protos\userAuth.proto" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.21.0-rc2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.46.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="2.46.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.46.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.46.3">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Grpc_Server_1\Grpc_Server_1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\userAuth.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

gRPC

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Protos\userAuth.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\userAuth.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.46.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.Storage" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.14.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I don't know if i need to change something in launchsettings or in the appsettings but what I give it's enough to understand what my doubt is

Any answer is welcome :)

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-grpc-json-transcoding-for-dotnet/ which might help. Alternatively you can use grpc-web and configure your gRPC .NET server to accept grpc-web.

Comment: What's the actual issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I would "hand-roll" it and avoid the mentioned libraries. Create the grpc client, publish that as a separate package and then you can consume that in your Web API where you need to.

I prefer this approach because it allows you to better control the mapping between the protobuf messages and what you expose to the consumer of the api (via REST I assume). You generally want your gRPC messages to have no opinions about how they are consumed. At least this has been my experience so far.

Perhaps my experience has been influenced by the reality that so-far I have been modernizing monolithic apps where we are still constrained by the existing database design. This often leads to EF entities that correspond to the db schema and then gRPC services that pretty much expose a repository so you get protobuf messaged that look like the entities which you will invariably want to map to / from the actual publicly exposed messages.